# File Handling in cpp

Tags: visual-c++, opencsv

I am working on my Project and new to c++. I have a question related to csv file. So, I am working with multiple cpp file in a same Project (for example main.cpp, first.cpp and second.cpp). In main.cpp, I am creating two csv file which have different Name whenever I run the Code and Iopen both csv file, writing 1st row in both csv file and then Close it. Now my question is: if I wanted to open and write on these both csv file in first.cpp and second.cpp then is it possible? If yes then how can I do that?

```
//main.cpp
void createcsv1()
{
//creating csv file1 and writing first row
}
void createcsv2()
{
//creating csv file2 and writing first row
}
int main()
{
void createcsv1();
void createcsv2();
System ("pause");
return 0;

//first.cpp

//second.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

To Open a file and perform file operations(read, write, seek, truncate), all you need is the Path to the file and appropriate permissions. 
I doesn't matter if you are reading from class 1 or class 2.

Try to open these two CSV files in the same way you are opening in main.cpp. you will get a file handle. Start writing in to the file using file handles.

Don't forget to close the file handle once after file operation is completed.

Example Code:

```
ofstream handle; 
handle.open ("example.txt");
handle << "basic example.\n";
handle.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 functions(createcsv1, createcsv2) in 2 cpp files.
You have to add declarations in stdafx.h.
Last, you can call functions in main() function.

```
int main()
{

void createcsv1();

void createcsv2();

System ("pause");

return 0;

}
```